# How to make a manual job always exit with success on GitLab CI?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

On my Gitlab CI I run the `gem https://rubygems.org/gems/brakeman` as a manual stage. When it finds any warning or error, on Gitlab CI **in the end, after it's gone through all the code**, it exits with `error 1` and gets rendered as yellow.

[image]

[image]

I want it to always exit with success - green. Then I'll examine its output myself for warnings and errors it found in my code.

How can I make it always return success and get rendered with the green colour?

Comment: Could you please add the (complete) output of brakeman as text?

Comment: If you do this then there is no purpose in running this job at all, as you could do this locally and inspect the output.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just prepend `| true` to your command for it to always succeed.

eg: `gem https://rubygems.org/gems/brakeman | true`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to modify your Brakeman command to include the `--no-exit-warn` and `--no-exit-error` options. Otherwise, it will set a non-zero error code if any warnings or recoverable errors are encountered.

I am assuming the exit code of `1` is not from Brakeman itself, as that would indicate an unhandled exception was raised, perhaps during the report generation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`allow_failure`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) option.

Your job would fail but the pipeline wouldn't.